# How does successCallback really work?

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I am so baffled by callback, as in I don't understand it at all. The API I am using has an ajax function like so:

```
"ajax": function ( method, url, data, successCallback, errorCallback ) {
$.ajax( {
        "type": method,
        "url":  url,
        "data": data,
        "dataType": "json",
        "success": function (json) {
            successCallback( json );
        },
        "error": function (xhr, error, thrown) {
            errorCallback( xhr, error, thrown );
        }
    } );
```

### From the API doc:

---

method  - string
The HTTP method to use for the AJAX request

url - string
The URL to submit the data to

data    - object
The data submitted to the server

successCallback - function
Callback function on data retrieval success

errorCallback   - function
Callback function on data retrieval error

---

What I don't understand is when I remove successCallback, the event does not complete. Why is this so? I have hit the "success" parameter, as in I've succsesfully run the ajax request, so what does the callback here do? I would think that anything in "success" is basically saying, "do this stuff after the ajax request is complete".

Thanks

Comment: `What I don't understand is when I remove successCallback, the event does not complete` What do you mean by not complete? Are you removing the function code declaration or just removing the function call inside success handler? And be aware, in your code, there is no complete callback defined, success is different than complete

Comment: If you remove the callback function how do you know that it has completed?

Comment: @ A. Wolff I am removing the function call inside success handler. Really I am trying to get someone to explain to me in..simple english.. what a successCallback does. My understanding is, if I hit "success" everything is peachy and anything I include in there is just stuff to do after. However it seems that it is integral to have a callback.

Comment: @  QuentinUK  So are you saying, it is "complete" that is looking for the  successCallback? Because I thought "complete" will automatically run after success and error is called.

Comment: @user3479138 But how do you check that complete callback is not fired? If you do nothing in success callback, then this doesn't stop complete callback to be fired. I'm really not sure to understand your question here

Comment: My question is, what the heck does successCallback do. Does it send something to complete? Is complete waiting for it? Keep in mind, somewhere in this API there is a complete function.

Comment: Sorry, successCallback is a function referred by parameter passed to ajax function. But again, it could be anything. You should train your skill with the many examples available on jquery's ajax method, it could be simpler to understand it. I'm not sure why you talk about complete callback as obviously, the 'API' you are using doesn't implement it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what API you are referring to, but `successCallback` is just a function.  That means it can do anything.  A callback is an executable block of code that you can pass as an argument.

```
api.ajax(method, url, data, function (json) {
    console.log(json);
}, function (err) {
    console.err(err);
});
```

The `function` will be called when the `success` method fires after the ajax request is successful.  The API is providing a way for you to pass your own custom code that is called when the ajax completes.

Comment: Yeah I'm even more baffled because a search through every file in the API yields no declaration of successCallback, but plenty of uses. ugh....

Comment: @user3479138 what is the API anyway?  This is an important question

Comment: Also I'm wondering, if I stick my own .ajax code in the 'success' portion, can I potentially make it wait for the now nested .ajax 'complete' function? Would that be a way of using callbacks?

Comment: The API is Editor https://editor.datatables.net/options/  If you expand the first heading (ajax) you will see what I am talking about.

Comment: @user3479138 yes you can nest ajax callbacks in this way if one ajax call relies on the result of another

Comment: @user3479138 the API says `Callback function on data retrieval success`

Answer (score 0):

In the API documentation, successCallback refers to the function set as the `success` property. The `success` handler is optional and if omitted, the ajax will still execute and complete.

You seem to think that you have to call something called `successFunction` from within the success handler. This is not the case. You can put anything you want in the success handler, or nothing it all, or just omitt it.

To illustrate, all of the following are valid usage of `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
     "type": method,
     "url": url,
     "success": function (json) {

      }
});

$.ajax({
     "type": method,
     "url": url,
     "success": function (json) {
          someFunction(); // providing this exists obviously
      }
});

$.ajax({
     "type": method,
     "url": url
});
```